# How do you select a security authentication modal with a css selector?

Tags: html, css

I am currently writing automated scripts to test an application. On one side of the site I log in using a css selector that points to a log in form. However, on the back end, the login form is a generic security authentication modal (See below). My question is how do I select the fields for the modal in my script so that my automated script can run?

[image: Generic Security Authentication Modal that I encounter]

Thanks,
      JD

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: You can't. The dialog isn't an html element part of your page.

Comment: Blahhh, thanks for the responses! Gonna have to ponder this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the credentials for http basic auth as part of the url:

```
 http://myUsername:myPassword@www.example.com
```